# Implementation of binary tree in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am planing to implement binary tree for recommendation
where a user can enroll any number of user but i want to keep all the user in binary tree

```
    A
   /  \
   B    c
  / \   / \
 D   E  F G
```

how can i store this data in database
i have tried creating model

```
class Tremodel(models.Model):
    refered_by = foreign key user
   left = foreign key user
  right = foreign key user
```

how can i query 15 level from there where A is the root but for the B/C tree start from it and B/C is the root where tree can go up to any level i just need to calculate up to 15 level in its branch

i tried creating the model i have shown above but i am totally confused how to query it`

Comment: You'll probably want to use django-treebeard or django-mptt instead.

Comment: i am thinking about the complexity that might occour while calculating 2^15 level for every user

Comment: Cool, and that's solved by the aforementioned libraries. Anyway, if a user can enroll any number of users (instead of up to two), how would a binary tree work?

Comment: In my case any new user will be at the bottom of the tree newcomer at the bottom

Comment: You will definitely need to explain your idea more - in your post, not in the comments. What's the _purpose_ of the tree?